# How to get an icon in stackPanel in a XAML file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to XAML and C#

I have an icon created already in a project and and I have to use this icon whenever I select one of the option from the dropdown menu.

I made a stackpanel in XAML file

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanelforIcon">
</StackPanel>
```

In the code behind file I have different cases for the dropdown menu.

```
case IconOnSelect:
?????? = IconList.NewIcon;
```

This NewIcon is the one already created and I am using the source also for this

```
using IconProject.Iconlists;
```

On writing IconList.NewIcon I am not getting any error, it is referenced correctly.

What should I write at ?????? to reference it. Is there any other way apart from using stackPanel to include an icon

Comment: I think you should show more code and xaml because what we have here is not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

A StackPanel cannot show an icon on it's own. You need a control for it, for example an [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanelforIcon">
    <Image x:Name=theImage" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then you can use your Icon in your code behind like this:

```
this.theImage.Source = IconList.NewIcon;
```

You may need to convert your value, you never said what type it actually is.

Please note that using code-behind is not the preferred way with WPF. Using MVVM is way easier and more natural working with WPF, using code-behind you will *fight* WPF all the way. Using MVVM, this could be:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanelforIcon">
    <Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage}" />
</StackPanel>
```

with your ViewModel having a property called `CurrentImage` that you would set when you want to change it. Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the changes to take effect though.